# C Pointers - Function pointer passed as a paramter

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

**Problem space:**

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding the syntax of the following final parameter, which is a function pointer passed as parameter:

```
    qsort(
        (void **) lineptr, 0, nlines - 1,

        /* Can't understand the following syntax */
        (int (*)(void*, void*))(numberic ? numcmp : strcmp)
    );
```

There's an alternative way that I do understand:

```
    int (*fn)(void*, void*);
    if(numeric) {
        fn = numcmp;
    } else {
        fn = strcmp;
    }
```

Also both of them generate compiler error: `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type`.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "alloc.h"
#include "line.h"
#include "qsort.h"
#include "numcmp.h"

char *lineptr[MAXLINES];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nlines; /* number of input lines read */
    int numeric = 0;

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-n") == 0)
        numeric = 1;

    if((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) {

        /* 
            qsort with custome soring function passed as a parameter
            throught pointers
        */
        int (*fn)(void*, void*);
        if(numeric) {
            fn = numcmp;
        } else {
            fn = strcmp;
        }

        qsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines - 1, fn);

        /*
            Alternative: 
            qsort(
                (void **) lineptr, 0, nlines - 1,
                (int (*)(void*, void*))(numberic ? numcmp : strcmp)
            );
        */

        printf("Sorted and tailed:\n");
        writelines(lineptr, nlines);

        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("error: input to big to sort\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear about the warning? (I assume you have read the manual for `qsort` and know its parameters.)

Comment: Nothing just wanted to point out, in case someone else would instead.
I guess I just have to change the pointer type to match with the functions.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes I did `man qsort`, and both of them seem to be `(const void *, const void *)`.

Comment: `(int (*)(void*, void*))whatever` is a cast of `whatever` to the corresponding type (a pointer to a function returning an int and taking two `void *` parameters).

Comment: The fact that you say "both" scares me, since `qsort` has *four* parameters.

Comment: @KerrekSB Haha sorry, what I mean was both parameters of the fourth parameter(which is a function pointer) seem to be `(const void *, const void *)`.

Comment: @Evert I guess it's a must that we include the parenthesis around the star: `(*)`, right? so we can't write: `(int *(void*, void*))whatever`?

Comment: Yes, the `(*)` ensures it is a function pointer. Precedence rules and such, which I only bother to look up when I need to actively write such code. I can roughly guess the meaning from just reading it.

Comment: Hint: If the code were clean, no cast would be necessary.

Comment: @Gene and presumably no compiler warning would be generated either? I'd like to see the declarations for `numcmp` and `strcmp`; I wonder if the former takes e.g. two doubles as argument, not two pointers.

Comment: @Gene I see, actually it's from K&R 2nd edition, I modified it tiny bit. =)

Comment: @Evert: `int numcmp(char const *s1, char const *s2);`, `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);`.

Comment: `int numcmp(char const *s1, char const *s2)`: I'm guessing the use of `char is old usage for a generic pointer, instead of `void *`. Because `char` and `num`(cmp) in the same function don't really make sense. Though I'm slightly more puzzled by the `char const *s1` order of `char` and `const`; compare `strcmp`, which has `const char *s1` instead. (quick look-up shows that these two are the same, just phrased differently; phew.)

Comment: Haha, sorry they should be `const char *`.

Comment: Well, qsort accepts, two `void *` parameters: `int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)`, but the other two functions accept `cost char *`, how would we overcome the compiler error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's essentially a cast from the result of the ternary expression to a function pointer that should the corresponding parameter in `qsort`. Thus, along the lines of `(a)b`, with `b` the ternary expression, and `a` your function pointer declaration.

`int (*)(void*, void*)` declares a pointer to a function that takes two `void *` arguments and returns an `int`.

Note on the `(*)`:

- if you remove the parentheses, you'll have a function that returns a pointer to an int.
- with the parentheses, you have a pointer to a function that returns an int.

Spot the difference.

---

There is the wonderful utility `cdecl` that can explain such declarations. Here it is for your case:

```
cdecl> explain (int (*)(void*, void*))
cast unknown_name into pointer to function (pointer to void, pointer to  void) returning int
```

(sadly, it appears to fail when using the ternary expression: `bad character ':'. You'll have to make that part up.)

Try it out online at [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/), or install it locally.

(A relevant discussion on deciphering C declarations [was on Hacker News recently](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12775735), where alternatives to the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) are mentioned.)

Comment: I see, one final silly question, so the whole statement is simply a cast to a function `(int (*)(void*, void*))(numberic ? numcmp : strcmp)`, so it would be in some sense equivalent to: `int d = 1; float f = (float)d`?

Comment: It is, in a *very* vague sense: only in the sense that they're both a cast. Plus, your compiler warning tell us that likely, in the actual case, the cast isn't really valid, and you can only hope for the best (but be prepared for a segmentation fault and data loss and such).

Comment: Yes, that's what I exactly meant. Casting an `int` to `float` seems to be simple, but casting an unknown function pointer with two parameters to a functions seems to be a little bit complicated, at least until I get used to it.

Comment: "seems to be a little bit complicated, at least until I get used to it". If you're bored with that, move on to a pointer to a function that takes, among others, an array of function pointers as an argument, and returns an array (pointer) of doubles. If you wonder about a use case: generic (multi-dimensional) optimisation routines for numerical work may show such things (though the array is better put as an argument than as a return value, and structures & typedefs help readability here).

Comment: Uh, I see. Yes I saw that we could have array of function pointers and pass it to another function, at that point my mind started blowing slightly, I was like hmm, what if I make a function pointer to `exit()` and pass it recursively to `int main(...)`, what would happen I wonder haha, alright the last one obviously is a joke. =)

Comment: What would happen is that your program would exit the first time it called `exit()`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I see, haha I can actually call `main()` recursively. =)

Comment: Anyways Guys, thanks for your efforts and the answer to my question. Much appreciated. =)

Comment: `man 3 exit`: "Note that exit() does nothing to prevent bottomless recursion should a function registered using atexit(3) itself call exit().  Such functions must call _Exit() instead (although this has other effects as well which
may not be desired)."